# How to filter this in the where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

So I have a table with 5 different codes and a bunch of amounts. I want to keep codes 1 through 4 no matter what the amount is. However, I want to remove records where the code is 5 and the amount = 0, but I want to keep code 5 when the amount <> 0. How do I go about this?

Comment: I've tried where code <> 5 and amount <> 0 but that removes all code 5

Comment: Almost there; you need to replace the `and` with `or`: `where code <> 5 OR amount <> 0`

Answer (score 2):

As per HoneyBadger comment Try like this,

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (
    Code INT
    ,Amount INT
    )
Insert into @MyTable
Values (1,100)
,(2,200)
,(3,300)
,(4,400)
,(5,500)
,(5,0)

SELECT *
FROM @MyTable
WHERE code <> 5
    OR amount <> 0
```